# Terminology: Degree of a power function

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, terminology

Consider a power function of the form

$$
f(x) = a \cdot x^r \qquad x \geq 0
$$

If $r$ is integer then usually $r$ is called "degree" of the power function. Is is also common to use this terminology if $r$ is non integer. For example "power function of degree 0.4".

If so, do you have some references for the use of this terminology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "degree" is usually reserved for polynomials, thus nonnegative integers $r$.  The more general term is "exponent".